# Single jQuery function to toggle multiple elements individually

Tags: jquery, html

I need a single jQuery function that can be re-used to toggle multiple elements individually. The code example on the jQuery page at http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/ works well for a single element using a button but not for multiple elements using non-button elements.

My code (adapted from the jQuery slidetoggle example):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>slideToggle demo</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="first">Toggle first</div>
    <p class="first">First hidden paragraph.</p>
<div class="second">Toggle second</div>
    <p class="second">Second hidden paragraph.</p>

<script>
$( "div.first" ).click(function() {
$( "p.first" ).slideToggle(0);
});
</script>

<script>
$( "div.second" ).click(function() {
$( "p.second" ).slideToggle(0);
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The code allows each  element to be toggled individually which is what I want. However, there are two problems with my code:

1. It is repetitive and inefficient in that a new script needs to be written for each element that I wish to make toggleable (I would prefer a single function that would toggle any element of a particular class name).
2. By default, the page is displayed with all elements displaying in full. I would prefer to have the toggleable elements hidden by default.

I have been unable to find a straightforward solution which addresses both issues. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Add a common class to alike elements - Check this : http://jsfiddle.net/VUs5W/

Comment: Shaunak, thanks but this only toggles between first and second, I need to be able to display both at the same time if necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use same class for all sets with event source. You can use only two classes for n number of html sets quite effectively.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3wCDB/1/)**

```
<div class="first">Toggle first</div>
    <p class="first-p">First hidden paragraph.</p>
<div class="first">Toggle second</div>
    <p class="first-p">Second hidden paragraph.</p>
```

Use current object with next()

```
$('.first-p').hide();   
$( "div.first" ).click(function() {
    $(this).next().slideToggle(1000);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function () {
    $(".first, .second")
    .filter("p")
    .toggle()
    .addBack()
    .not("p")
    .click(function (e) {
       return $("." + e.target.className).not("div").slideToggle(0)
    });
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/6aMk7/

Comment: In case anyone wants the explanation to the above : Use multiple element selectors in your $('...') call, separated by commas.